# Tikz - Custom number of points on axis and equally linespace

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

How can I reproduce this plot?

[image]

This is for now my code. I miss only add an equaly linespace on x-axis and the points `(k-f_s(k))`.

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz,convert={outext=.svg,command=\unexpanded{pdf2svg \infile\space\outfile}},multi=false]{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{customPurple}{HTML}{812C7C}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  every tick label/.append style={font=\footnotesize},
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1.5cm]
    \begin{axis}[
      grid=both,
      xlabel={Key},
      ylabel={Position},
      grid style={thin,densely dotted,black!20},
      ytick=data,
    ]
      \addplot[only marks, mark size=1.5pt, black] coordinates{
        (27,0)
        (29,1)
        (32,2)
        (32,3)
        (33,4)
        (37,5)
        (37,6)
        (37,7)
        (38,8)
        (40,9)
        (41,10)
        (43,11)
        (44,12)
        (46,13)
      };
      % eq: 11y = 8x - 223
      \draw[customPurple, thick] (axis cs:27,-0.63) -- (axis cs:46,13.18) ; 
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's advised that you post a screenshot of the result of the current code.

Comment: Try [axis - Label certain value on axes for pgfplots - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528482/label-certain-value-on-axes-for-pgfplots) and [tikz pgf - Drawing from a specific x-axis value to a line intersection then to y-axis - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476096/drawing-from-a-specific-x-axis-value-to-a-line-intersection-then-to-y-axis) .